# Incorrect JavaList objects being removed caused by bad nested for-loop?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want my nested for-loop to remove any word that contains any letter pre-defined from a character arraylist (arr1), the word is removed from a string arraylist (arr2).

The program quits prematurely after it enters the "word remover" method (exit code 0) and doesn't reach the print method after.

Here is the for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++){ //for each character in the array
            for (String s : arr2) { //for each word on the word list
                for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) { //for each words letter
                    if (s.charAt(k) == arr1.get(i)){
                        arr2.remove(s);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I attempted to re-write the loop a few times, I've tried using the outer-loop to start iterating through each word then going through each words letters and cross referencing it with arr1 and vice versa. I'm positive that the arrayList for the bad characters, as well as importing the words from the txt file into a string arraylist is correct since when testing it prints out properly.

This is the full output:

```
What word was entered? (Common starter word is Crane) 
crane
Successfully initialized word: crane
Enter the results of the initial guess in order from first letter to last letter (B = black (not used), G = green (correct spot), Y = yellow (used, but in the wrong spot), for example: BGYYB 
bbybb
Added bad letter: c
Added bad letter: r
Added possible letter: a
Added bad letter: n
Added bad letter: e

Finished looping through the results...
Successfully added all good or bad letters
The possible letters so far are: 
a 
The bad letters so far are: 
c r n e 
The word we have so far is: 
LetterSorter() finished

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I attached the entire code below for some more context but I'm puzzled as to what I did wrong. There's a lot of "extra" code that is either unused/planned to be deleted so it may look very janky please excuse my poor style

https://github.com/DanAlbertSolis/wordleSolver/blob/master/src/wordleSolver.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loop from end of the collection, remove should work correctly.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++){ //for each character in the array
        for (int j = arr2.size() - 1 ; j >= 0; j--) { //for each word on the word list
            String s  = arr2.get(j);
            for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) { //for each words letter
                if (s.charAt(k) == arr1.get(i)){
                    arr2.remove(j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Petr! I tried this code block and it worked successfully! I'm not sure why starting at index 0 vs. index n made the difference but I'm happy that it did. Thanks again

Comment: I think it is because when you remove an element, indexes following elements are messed. When you start from 0, it is problem because you are going to following indexes. If you start with n it is not problem, because you will not encounter these messed indexes any more.